# How to get parameter from previous context in Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I am creating a chatbot for an IP firm. Its have an entity named `service` to have 4 type values. (Patent, Copyright, Trademark, design).

> Client: What is a patent?
>
> Bot: (Answer)
>
> Client: how much cost to file it?

How I can know client asking about the patent from the previous context?

I can't use followup-intent in every intent.

Right now I'm using a global variable to get the slot `agent.parameters.Service` inside fulfillment.

```
let slot='patent';
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  function service_typeHandler(agent){
    var serv ='';
    serv = agent.parameters.Service;

    if(serv ===''){
      serv=slot;
    }
    else{
      slot=serv;
    }

    switch( serv ){
      case 'patent':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're correct on two fronts:

1. Don't use followup Intents. There are few cases where you actually want followup Intents. Most of the time you want to do this with other means.
2. Use [Contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). These are (part of) the "other means" in most cases.

In this case, it sounds like you'll have two Intents (and likely more, but this illustrates the point):

- "ask.what" - which is the user saying things like "What is a patent?"
- "ask.price" - which is the user saying things like "How much to file a patent?", but also "How much to file it?"

For the "ask.what" Intent, you would set an "Outgoing Context". This will automatically capture the parameters that are attached to the Intent. If you want to control it more yourself, you can create your own Context in your webhook and set parameters to whatever value you want. I suggest the latter, because it lets you use a parameter name that you don't use elsewhere. Let's assume that you're using a context named "savedInfo" and that you're setting the parameter to "savedService".

In your "ask.price" Intent, you'd do something similar to what you're doing now. Except that if the `Service` parameter is empty, get the parameters from the "savedInfo" context and, specifically, the `savedService` parameter.